# condition of uniformly continuity on $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \max\{0,1-|x-2n|\}$

Tags: analysis, uniform-continuity

[condition for uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \max\{0,1-|x-2n|\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4163824/condition-for-uniform-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-max-0-1-x-2n/4163893#4163893)

Now slightly modified and figure out necessary and sufficient condition for uniform continuity of $     \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \operatorname{max}\{1-|x-2n|,0\}, \quad x \in [0,\infty)$.

i.e.,

Let $a_n$ be a non-negative real numbers and define
\begin{align}
  f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \operatorname{max}\{1-|x-2n|,0\}, \quad x \in [0,\infty). 
\end{align}
I want to find necessary and sufficient conditions on $a_n$ for the function $f$ to be uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

---

Following are my trial

Recall the definition of uniformly continuous of $f$

> $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous if $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta >0$ such that $\forall x ,y \in D$, $|x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(y) | < \epsilon.$

From the comment of @Kavi Rama Murthy, pick $x \in (2n-1, 2n+1)$ I noticed that $
\sum_{k=n}^{m} a_k \max\{1-|x-2k|,0\} \leq  \max\{a_n, \cdots, a_m\}$ for $x\in (2n-1, 2n+1)$ and $n<m$, But since here I am considering uniform continuity, so $x,y \in [0,\infty)$, but since the value $f(x)$ does not depend on the choice of $x$ it seems $f(x) = f(y)$ which seems wrong.

Comment: Is this your exercise? Because the question seems so artificially crafted.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen, sort of. Actually, I am trying to extend this problem to uniform convergence-> uniformly continuous -> and relaxing summation with equi-continuous.

Comment: You can do just the same thing here. Consider each interval $(2n-1,2n+1)$, you can see that each interval is Lipschitz and prove that the condition for uniform continuity is just the same as the previous question.